# Unit test private method in c++ using a friend class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, class, c++11

I know that this is a debated practice, but let's suppose that this is the best option for me. I am wondering about what is the actual technique to do this. The approach that I see is this:

1) Make a friend class that of the class who's method I want to test.

2) In the friend class, create a public method(s) that call the private method(s) of the tested class.

3) Test the public methods of the friend class.

Here is a simple example to illustrate the above steps:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
  friend class MyFriend; // Step 1

  private:
  int plus_two(int a)
  {
    return a + 2;
  }
};

class MyFriend
{
public:
  MyFriend(MyClass *mc_ptr_1)
  {
    MyClass *mc_ptr = mc_ptr_1;
  }

  int plus_two(int a) // Step 2
  {
    return mc_ptr->plus_two(a);
  }
private:
  MyClass *mc_ptr;
};

int main()
{
  MyClass mc;
  MyFriend mf(&mc);
  if (mf.plus_two(3) == 5) // Step 3
    {
      std::cout << "Passed" << std::endl;
    }
  else
    {
      std::cout << "Failed " << std::endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Edit:

I see that in the discussion following one of the answers people are wondering about my code base.

My class has methods that are called by other methods; none of these methods should be called outside the class, so they should be private. Of course they could be put into one method, but logically they are much better separate. These methods are complicated enough to warrant unit testing, and due to performance issues I will very likely have to re-factor these methods, hence it would be nice to have a test to make sure that my re-factoring didn't break anything. I am not the only one working on the team, though I am the only one who is working on this project including the tests.

Having said the above, my question was not about whether it is a good practice to write unit tests for private methods, though I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Here's a questionable suggestion for a questionable question. I don't like the coupling of friend as then released code has to know about the test. Nir's answer below is one way to alleviate that, but I still don't much like changing the class to conform to the test. Since I don't rely on inheritance often, I sometimes just make the otherwise private methods protected and have a test class inherit and expose as needed. I expect at least three "boo hisses" for this comment, but the reality is that the public API and the testing API can differ and still be distinct from the private API. Meh.

Comment: @JTrana: Why not write that up as a proper answer?

Comment: Ok. This is not one of those ones you feel super-proud about, but hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An alternative to friend (well, in a sense) that I use frequently is a pattern that I've come to know as access_by. It's pretty simple:

```
class A {
  void priv_method(){};
 public:
  template <class T> struct access_by;
  template <class T> friend struct access_by;
}
```

Now, suppose class B is involved in testing A. You can write this:

```
template <> struct access_by<B> {
  call_priv_method(A & a) {a.priv_method();}
}
```

You can then use this specialization of access_by to call private methods of A. Basically, what this does is put the onus of declaring friendship into the header file of the class that wants to call A's private methods. It also lets you add friends to A without changing A's source. Idiomatically, it also indicates to whoever reads the source of A that A does not indicate B a true friend in the sense of extending its interface. Rather, the interface of A is complete as given and B needs special access into A (testing being a good example, I've also used this pattern when implementing boost python bindings, sometimes a function that needs to be private in C++ is handy to expose into the python layer for the implementation).

Comment: Curious about a valid use case for making the `friend access_by`, isnt the first non-friend sufficient - being a nested struct it would have access to everything within A? eg. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/663dd17ed2acd7a3

Answer (score 12):

**If it's hard to test, it's badly written**

If you have a class with private methods complex enough to warrant their own test, the class is doing too much.  Inside there is another class trying to get out.

Extract the private methods that you want to test into a new class (or classes) and make them public.  Test the new classes.

In addition to making the code easier to test, this refactoring will make the code easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer, if you can't test your private methods completely by testing the public methods, something is not right and refactoring the private methods to their own class would be a good solution.

Comment: In my codebase, a class has a very complex method that initializes a computational graph. It calls several sub-functions in sequence to achieve various aspects of this. Each sub-function is quite complicated, and the sum total of the code is very complicated. However, the sub-functions are meaningless if not called on this class and in the right sequence. All the user cares about is the computational graph being fully initialized; the intermediates are worthless to the user. Please, I'd like to hear how I should refactor this, and why it makes more sense than just testing the private methods.

Comment: @Nir: Do the trivial: extract a class with all those methods public, and make your existing class a facade around the new class.

Comment: This answer is correct but it really depends on the data you are working with.In my case I am not provided with actual testing data so I have to create some by observing real time data and then "inject" it into my application and see how it goes.A single piece of data is too complex to handle so it would be much easier to artificially create partial testing data that is only a subset of the realtime data to target each than actually reproduce the realtime data.The private function are not complex enough to call for implementation of several other small class (with the respective functionality)

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be testing private methods. Period. The classes using your class only care about the methods that it provides, not the ones it uses under the hood to work.

If you're worrying about your code coverage, you need to find configurations that allow you to test that private method from one of the public method calls. If you can't do that, what's the point of having the method in the first place? It's simply unreachable code.

Comment: Strongly disagree. Those classes may only care about interface, not implementation, but you as the developer care about both. The whole point of having unit tests is not only to see when a change causes something to fail, but also to provide information so you can fix it as quickly as possible. Testing private methods directly can yield more informative tests.

Comment: The point of private methods is to ease development (through seperation of concerns, or maintaining DRY, or any number of things) but are meant to be non permanent. They are private for that reason. They could appear, disappear, or change in functionality drastically from one implementation to the next, which is why tying them to unit tests is not always practical, or even useful.

Comment: It may not always be practical or useful, but that's a very far cry from saying that you should never be testing them. You are talking about the private methods as though they are somebody else's private methods; "they could appear, disappear...". No, they could not. If you are unit testing them directly, it should only be because you maintain them yourself. If you change the implementation, you change the tests.

In short, your blanket statement is unjustified. While it's good to warn the OP about this, his question is still justified, and your answer doesn't actually answer it.

Comment: What guarantee do you have that you'll be writing the tests for your code? Why couldn't some guy 3 cubes down be writing the tests for your code (possibly better tests than you could)? If OP is a one man team, sure, he's got lots of guarantees about what's going on, but if he, like many other developers, are part of a team, you can't take anything for granted.

Comment: Let me also note: the OP said up front he's aware that it's a debated practice. So if he wants to do it anyway, maybe he really does have good reasons for it? Neither of us know the details of his codebase. In the code I work with, we have some very experienced and expert programmers, and they thought it was useful to unit test private methods in some cases.

Comment: Now you are getting into details of development cycle, and frankly are just proving my point. Yes, if your development cycle is such and such, then perhaps this is not suitable. I know for example in my case, you generally have to include unit tests when adding new code (depends on the exact circumstances, not going to enumerate all the cases). This is actually a pretty good workflow in many cases. So yes, when I write a private method, I can guarantee I will write its tests, because it won't be merged otherwise.

Comment: -1, an answer like "You shouldn't be testing private methods." is IMHO not helpful. The topic when to test and when not to test private methods has been discussed on this site sufficiently. The OP has shown that he is aware of this discussion, and its clearly he is looking for solutions under the assumption that in his case testing private methods is the way to go.

Comment: @DocBrown Isn't the question off topic then?

Comment: @BЈовић: I think it is debatable if such a question is better suited for stackoverflow.com since it is specific for C++. For me, it seems to be an edge case.

Comment: I think the problem here is that this may be a very classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in that OP thinks he needs to unit test his private methods for one reason or another, when in reality he could approach the testing from a more pragmatic viewpoint, viewing the private methods as mere helper functions for the public ones, which are the contract with the end users of the class.

Comment: @BЈовић - no. Just because you don't like the OP's dev process doesn't make the question invalid.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Yes, see [what is on topic](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This falls under "implementation issues".

Comment: I initially posted the question on StackOverflow, but a comment suggesting to move it to Programmers quickly got 2 or 3 upvotes, so I moved it here.

Comment: I think the fundamental problem here is that people are acting as though the delineation of units in an interface sense, and units in a testing sense should be identical. They are not.

In a class, what is private or public is determined solely by what the designer deems the user requires access to in order to achieve whatever the goal of the class is.

In unit testing, as much as it is generally preferable to test interfaces, fundamental testing units are built around complexity: too little and you have too many useless tests, too much and your tests are not an effective tool.

Comment: I agree. If you're going to arbitrarily decide which methods are private wand which are public, then you need an equally arbitrary method of testing them. If you're looking at your methods from a functional perspective or an object oriented perspective, you should plan your public and private methods accordingly, and then test those public methods upon which other classes depend.

Comment: Let's take an example: suppose you are doing some super sophisticated numeric integration. Your users are scientists that need very fast accurate integrals, but know nothing about the details. Their only interface is to pass the integrand and interval to a function, and receive the value.

The interface here is very simple, the only unit tests you can write are to give some examples of integrands and integrals. However, when a change in the codebase occurs, all you will see is that your unit tests are all wrong. You will have no idea where to start looking at your code to fix it.

Comment: So your entire program is held in one class **and** doing a super sophisticated numeric integration, and you're concerned about your unit tests? I've got some bad news for you: your classes are way too big.

Comment: Your solution apparently would either be to:
a) change the interface, or b) simply live with these tests. Both these options suck. The far more reasonable thing to do is to test some of the private methods of the numerical integrator. In fact, let's be honest, while you were writing the numerical integrator, you probably wrote some tests like that to help you. Rather than making those unit tests, you delete them to rigidly stick to your ideology? Frankly it's just silly.

Comment: Who said anything about one class? My larger NumericIntegrator class may have subclasses as members: privately nested classes. These nested classes may hold a lot of complexity and be worth testing on their own, but in your world, they won't be tested independently because they're not part of the interface.

Comment: So really, the issue in your example is that you privately nested all of your useful functionality, making it impossible to unit test, thereby requiring you to modify your class to accept a third party inside to run the unit tests. Why not just break out your nested inner classes and test them independently? The only use case where you *need* to have a friend come in and test your code is when your class is so poorly written and huge that you have no other way of getting to the important code.

Comment: No, I did not privately nest the useful functionality; the useful functionality is the ability to integrate, which is public. I don't have any need to break out the inner classes because my user has no need of them. Notice your leading sentence: "... making it impossible to unit test". You want to design interfaces around testability, rather than the needs of your user. Talk about putting the cart before the horse.

You have basically decided that there should be a limit on the amount of complexity encapsulated without user interface. I don't know how you came to this conclusion.

Comment: So the only functionality allowed to be public is functionality the end user uses? That seems pointlessly complex doesn't it? Are you worried about your user getting access to methods they shouldn't use? They can use reflection to get around your private classes anyway...

Comment: Your problem is: you both talk about different levels of a "public API": the API of a complex component to the potential users, and the public API of the classes of the components, which should be exposed to other classs within the component, but not to the outside. C++ has no "internal" keyword, like C#, so there is no simple mechanics to describe these different forms of "public", but there are different forms of workarounds. One valid workaround is the use of private nested classes, and in that context, testing private methods could make sense.

Comment: I don't know, does it seem pointlessly complex? You're awfully confident about code you haven't seen. Sometimes you want an operation to be atomic to the user, but it may have many well defined, individually complex logical units inside. You don't want to make the internal units (could be classes, functions, etc) public, because if the user calls them out of sequence or at the wrong time, they can break the state of your class. Initializing a computational graph is an example of an operation that should be atomic to the user, but is extremely complicated and has many sub-steps inside.

Comment: Anyhow, this has already gone ridiculously long enough. It boils down to: you seem unable to conceive of a situation where the logical units (classes/functions) you want to expose to your user, and the logical units you want to test, are different. Complexity of implementation is a minor factor in deciding what to expose to the user, but the largest factor in deciding how to test. Yet somehow you have constrained your logical units in both cases to be identical. Have fun designing your next project, I just hope it's nowhere near me.

Comment: Nonsense to say you shouldn't test a private method. Private methods can contain bugs in their inmplementation too.

Yes you should test them.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options to do this, but keep in mind that they (in essence) modify the public interface of your modules, to give you access to internal implementation details (effectively transforming unit testing into tightly coupled client dependencies, where you should have *no* dependencies at all).

- you could add a friend (class or function) declaration to the tested class.
- you could add `#define private public` to the beginning of your test files, before `#include`-ing the tested code. In case the tested code is an already-compiled library though, this could make the headers no longer match already compiled binary code (and cause UB).
- you could insert a macro in your tested class and decide at a later date what that macro means (with a different definition for testing code). This would allow you to test internals, but it would also allow third party client code to hack into your class (by creating their own definition in the declaration you add).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a questionable suggestion for a questionable question. I don't like the coupling of friend as then released code has to know about the test. Nir's answer is one way to alleviate that, but I still don't much like changing the class to conform to the test.

Since I don't rely on inheritance often, I sometimes just make the otherwise private methods protected and have a test class inherit and expose as needed. The reality is that the public API and the testing API can differ and still be distinct from the private API, which leaves you in sort of a bind.

Here's a practical example that's of the sort I resort to this trick for. I write embedded code, and we rely on state machines quite a bit. The external API doesn't necessarily need to know about the internal state machine state, but the test should (arguably) test conformance to the state machine diagram in the design doc. I might expose a "current state" getter as protected and then give the test access to that, allowing me to test the state machine more fully. I often find this type of class hard to test as a black box.

Comment: While it is a Java approach, this is quite standard to make private functions default level instead allowing other classes in the same package (the test classes) to be able to see them.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code with lots of workarounds to stop you having to use friends.

You can write classes and never have any private methods at all. All you need to then do is make implementation functions within the compilation unit, let your class call them and pass in any data members they need to access.

And yes it will mean you can change the signatures or add new "implementation" methods without changing your header in the future.

You have to weigh up though whether or not it is worth it. And a lot will really depend on who is going to see your header.

If I'm using a 3rd party library I'd rather not see friend declarations to their unit testers. I don't want to build their library either and have their tests run when I do. Unfortunately too many 3rd party open source libraries I have built do that.

Testing is the job of the writers of the library, not its users.

However not all classes are visible to the user of your library. Lots of classes are "implementation" and you implement them the best way to ensure they work properly. In those, you may still have private methods and members but want unit testers to test them. So go ahead and do it that way if that will lead to robust code quicker, that is easy to maintain for those who need to do so.

If the users of your class are all within your own company or team, you can also relax a bit more about that strategy, assuming it's allowed by your company's coding standards.